# Emacs: how to end sentences on encountering a newline

Tags: emacs

The commands `M-a (backward-sentence)` and `M-e (forward-sentence)` move to the beginning and end of the current sentence, respectively. I would like to end a sentence if there is a newline. So, I would like emacs to treat the following text as two lines (even though there are no periods). With the default config, emacs treats it as a single sentence.

```
This is line one
This is line two
```

**Why do I need this?**

I use `visual-line-mode`. So my sentences never contain a newline character. I am using the `sentence hilight mode` which relies on emacs "sentence end". This creates problem in cases where there are no periods. For example program source listing. (The whole program is treated as a single line by emacs.)

Comment: It sounds like everything is working correctly, except `sentence-highlight-mode` needs to be tweaked?  I.e., you are seeking a modification of `sentence-highlight-mode` so that it highlights even if there are no periods at the end of a line, but instead contain a new-line -- e.g., `\n`?  Or, is `backward-sentence` and `forward-sentence` not behaving as you expect because there are no periods?

Comment: @lawlist Current behavior: If the cursor is on line one, `sentence-hilight-mode` highlights both the lines.
Desired behavior: If the cursor is on line one, `sentence-hilight-mode` should highlight only line one. (This happens because Emacs treats both the lines as a single sentence.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding `\n` to the end of the regexp for `sentence-end` should accomplish the goal you seek -- it is done by adding a delimiter that looks like this `\\|` and then the `\n`.

Here is the default regexp for `sentence-highlight-mode`:

```
(setq sentence-end "[^.].[.?!]+\\([]\"')}]*\\|<[^>]+>\\)\\($\\| $\\|\t\\| \\)[ \t\n]*")
```

Here is the *revised* regexp for `sentence-highlight-mode`:

```
(setq sentence-end "[^.].[.?!]+\\([]\"')}]*\\|<[^>]+>\\)\\($\\| $\\|\t\\| \\)[ \t\n]*\\|\n")
```